# Exchange Server 2010 mailbox not working or changing password

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

This has given me a immense head ache all day.

I have a AD user that I have changed the password for, but the mailbox password won't change.

I cannot login to that mailbox at all..

I've tried iisreset, i've also tried gpupdate /force. I've even tried deleting the user from AD and recreating her.

She can't login to her mailbox, I have tried everything I can think of, all other 32 users are fine.

Help!!

Comment: "I cannot login to that mailbox at all" - details please... Are you trying through OWA? Have you checked the IIS logs? See if you get any authentication failures in the Security log on the Domain Controllers or if the badPwdCount on the user object increases

Comment: Just so you are aware, with AD and Exchange, there is no "mailbox password", its one and the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience if the user is logging in via owa after a password change you need to make sure that you un-check the "User must change password at next login" box in their properties in ADUC.

If that fails try logging into a workstation and see if the workstation provides an error code rather than just a failed login attempt.

Comment: OMG - I unticked this box and it now works..... so simple and i've wasted hours on it.... Thanks DKNUCKLES

Comment: Happy to help - it's a rather weird nuance with Exchange 2010 that took me some time to figure out as well.

Comment: Strange...if I do a password reset on exchange 2010 they get prompted to set a new password when they first login to owa just like they would on a domain pc.